# Return one field per row for multiple rows and transform them into a single row of values to be displayed

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Looking for suggestions...

I've got a table that has project data and another table that contains a list of project readiness levels.  Since it's likely the project will have many readiness levels and each readiness level can be assigned to many project, this has the potential to create a many-to-many relationship so I created a junction table to avoid that.

```
The junction table is simply:
   projectID (int),
   readinessLevelID (int), (the range of values is 1-9 for this field)
   readinessLevelDate (date)
```

Since there will be multiple rows for each project, and all I need to return is the readinessLevelDate field for each readinessLevel, I'd like to append these dates on to the end of a record in a project data query instead of creating a row for each readinessLevel (potentially 9 or more rows per project).  Each project may go up (or down) the readiness level scale based on testing and evaluation, therefore projects may contain multiple records for many levels.  And, of course, all management wants to see is the latest date each level was achieved.

I tried creating a Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[return_Readiness_Level_Dates] (@Proj_ID Int)
--ALTER  Proc [dbo].[return_Readiness_Level_Dates] (@Proj_ID Int)
As

Declare  @readDate Date

Select   @readDate = max(readinessLevelDate)
From     projectReadinessLevel
Where    projectID = @Proj_ID AND readinessLevelID = 1

return @readDate ;
```

This returns the error, "Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure return_TRL_Level_Dates, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 7]
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int"

First question is, how do I tell the SP that I want to return a "date" value?  (Obviously, it's trying to return an "int."

Without the return value (@readDate), the SP runs and returns "0" (the "int").

Next question is, will the SP return a data row that can be appended to a recordset and be displayed?

The initial thought was to create an output variable that would contain a date for each readiness level achieved but, I can't find an example of how to pass that back to the calling procedure in C#.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current syntax is more like a scalar [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql).

In the procedure, `return @readDate;` is causing the error. In procedures you do not `return` values like that, but you can `return` status codes (which are integers).

For returning data from a [procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql), you can either return rowsets by `select`, or you could use `output` parameters.

e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[return_Readiness_Level_Dates] (@Proj_ID Int)
--ALTER  Proc [dbo].[return_Readiness_Level_Dates] (@Proj_ID Int)
As
begin;
Declare  @readDate Date

Select   @readDate = max(readinessLevelDate)
From     projectReadinessLevel
Where    projectID = @Proj_ID AND readinessLevelID = 1

Select    readDate = @readDate
end;
```

Which could be simplified to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[return_Readiness_Level_Dates] (@Proj_ID Int)
--ALTER  Proc [dbo].[return_Readiness_Level_Dates] (@Proj_ID Int)
As
begin;
Select   readDate = max(readinessLevelDate) 
From     projectReadinessLevel
Where    projectID = @Proj_ID AND readinessLevelID = 1
end;
```

---

If you want to return 9 `readinessLevelDate` in a single row, you could use conditional aggregation like so:

```
create procedure dbo.return_readiness_level_dates (@Proj_ID int) as 
begin;
set nocount on;
select 
    ProjectId 
  , Level_1_Ready_Date = max(case when readinessLevelId = 1 then readinessLevelDate end)
  , Level_2_Ready_Date = max(case when readinessLevelId = 2 then readinessLevelDate end)
  , Level_3_Ready_Date = max(case when readinessLevelId = 3 then readinessLevelDate end)
  , Level_4_Ready_Date = max(case when readinessLevelId = 4 then readinessLevelDate end)
  , Level_5_Ready_Date = max(case when readinessLevelId = 5 then readinessLevelDate end)
  , Level_6_Ready_Date = max(case when readinessLevelId = 6 then readinessLevelDate end)
  , Level_7_Ready_Date = max(case when readinessLevelId = 7 then readinessLevelDate end)
  , Level_8_Ready_Date = max(case when readinessLevelId = 8 then readinessLevelDate end)
  , Level_9_Ready_Date = max(case when readinessLevelId = 9 then readinessLevelDate end)
from ProjectReadinessLevel
where ProjectId = @Proj_ID
group by ProjectId;
end;
go
```

Comment: thanks, that works for ONE readiness level.  Now, as I mentioned in the original post, each project will have up to 9 readiness level dates that need to be returned and displayed (using C# code).
1) If I take your suggestion and create a scalar function, how do I assign multiple variables to the output recordset when each select statement returns only one date?  
2)Or, do I just need to call the function 9 times passing in the expected readiness level?  
3) Or, can I return multiple output variables using return var1, var2...?

Comment: @RLoomas I would use conditional aggregation or `pivot()` to return a single row with all 9 dates for a given `ProjectId`. Answer updated with an example

Comment: would you provide an example or a link to a post here that has one?

Comment: @RLoomas I added an example at the bottom of my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43689115/2333499 and here is a rextester demo: http://rextester.com/YMERY16893

Comment: sorry for the long pause here, I got diverted to a different problem.  I love the conditional aggregation and it does exactly what I'm looking for.  I was even able to create a "view" using that functionality which makes it easier for our programmers to call from their forms...